# What is the jQuery plugin to add new line of textboxes after clicking a button

Tags: jquery

I am developing an admin panel where there is a button called "Add New Tutorial". If I click on this button, a new line will appear above this button for the user to enter the information or data.

This new line that will appear will consists of a text box and a drop down select. User can then enter the information on the textbox and select values from the drop down.

I'm not experienced with jQuery so I hope someone can point an example of any sites using this or some code examples that I can use. Thanks.

Comment: Like @DarshanTanki say in a (not very nice) way is http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a nice tutorial on how to add form fields using jQuery.

[Here](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/)